# Passing a struct to a thread, how access multiple data in struct?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem. I need to use a struct of OpenCV Mat images for passing multiple arguments to a thread.

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Args
{
    Mat in[6];
    Mat out[6];
};
```

And a void function called by thread, like this:

```
void grey (void *param){
    while (TRUE)
    {
    WaitForSingleObject(mutex,INFINITE);
    Args* arg = (Args*)param;
    cvtColor(*arg->in,*arg->out,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    ReleaseMutex(mutex);
    _endthread();
    }
}
```

For launch the grey function as thread with two Mat array arguments, I use the follow line in main:

```
Args dati;
    *dati.in = *inn;
    *dati.out = *ou;


handle1 = (HANDLE) _beginthread(grey,0,&dati);
```

Now, my problem is: I need to access to all 6 elements of two array "in" and "out" in struct passed to thread from thread itself or however, find a mode to shift array from 0 to 5 to elaborate all elements with the "grey" functions.

How can I do this from thread or from main? I mean using grey function for elaborate all 6 elements of array Mat in[6] of struct Args that I pass to thread in that mode.

Can someone help me or gime me an idea? I don't know how do this.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.. In case you mean to say that you want to pass variable values to thread while it has already been created, you can consider using "Queues"....

Comment: Your thread already have all six entries in the arrays in the structure, you are just setting and accessing the first entry though. If you want to make a copy of the arrays in the thread, so your shuffling won't change the arrays in the structure, then just create new arrays in the thread function and [copy it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: Also, why have the loop in the thread-function, when you exit the thread as soon as you release the mutex?

Comment: Exactly ... how can I do to process all six pictures in a single thread? Can I do it? Or do I have to create a thread for each individual image? How can I create a queues?

I apologize for the question, but it is only recently that I have to deal with threads ...

Comment: Loop over them? `for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { /* use arg->in[i] */ }`? Of course, that requires you to properly set the array before passing it to the array, which you don't do now.

Comment: In fact, if I do it now, don't work. How should I set array before, so I can do this? Thank you very much for your time!You're very kind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch your thread, this code:

```
Args dati;
*dati.in = *inn;
*dati.out = *ou;
```

is only initialising one of the six elements. If `inn` and `ou` are actually 6 element arrays, you will need a loop to initialise all 6.

```
Args dati;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  dati.in[i] = inn[i];
  dati.out[i] = ou[i];
}
```

Similarly, in your thread, you're only processing the first element in the array. So this code:

```
Args* arg = (Args*)param;
cvtColor(*arg->in,*arg->out,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

would need to become something like this:

```
Args* arg = (Args*)param;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  cvtColor(arg->in[i],arg->out[0],CV_BGR2GRAY);
}
```

Comment: This modify, don't work...Visual C++ don't compile...why?? :(

Comment: Assuming `inn` and `ou` are the actual names of your source arrays, then I mistyped the `ou` variable as `out` in the first loop. Have updated my answer. If that's not the problem, you'll need to provide the full definition for those variables. I'm just guessing how they're defined.

Comment: I post complete code to make you understand. I post it like an answer,ok? Thanks in advance for your patience.

Comment: You removed the line `Args* arg = (Args*)param;` when adding the loop to the `cvtColor` call. Also you don't need to do `std::copy` if you're using a loop to copy the elements. Either way should work - pick whichever you prefer. Although if you want to use `std::copy` I think you'll need to add another include.

Answer (score 2):

Before you create the thread, you assign the array like this:

```
*dati.in = *inn;
*dati.out = *ou;
```

This will only assign *the first* entry in the array. The rest of the array will be untouched.

You need to copy *all* of the source array into the destination array. You can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) for this:

```
std::copy(std::begin(dati.in), std::end(dati.in), std::begin(inn));
```

Of course, that requires that the source "array" `inn` contains *at least* as many items as the destination array.

Then in the thread simply loop over the items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    cvtColor(arg->in[i], arg->out[i], CV_BGR2GRAY);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how do this: how can copy all the array? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @Domenico The `std::copy` function handles it. That's what it does, copy stuff.